# Raspberry pi to adafruit fingerprint scanner

Tags: raspi-config

i am a newbie in raspberry, can you help me with my project
Guys how to connect the adafruit finger print scanner to my raspberry and how could i store the libraries of the finger print in my raspberry?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45497/discussion-on-question-by-ivan-lamoca-raspberry-pi-to-adafruit-fingerprint-scann).

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please edit the requested information directly into the question (you can edit your own questions).

Answer (score 0):

From an [older question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7702/raspberry-pi-and-fingerprint-scanner):

> That should work just fine. It uses the UART protocol, so it should be easy to cable (Only 2 wires to the UART GPIO pins (14 and 15 IIRC). As far as the libraries, I think all you will find is the 'demo software' download from Sparkfun's website. In the SDK(Software Development Kit) there are some cpp (C++) files, and some .h (header) files. I think between these and the datasheet you should have a pretty good chance at getting it working.